# Removing tuples that contain specific elements (cards)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, playing-cards

So let's say  I have a list of cards (tuples). E.g.,

`[('H[A]', 'S[2]'), ('H[A]', 'H[3]'), ('H[A]', 'H[4]')....]`

H[A]: Ace of Hearts & S[2]: 2 of Spades.

The list of cards represents all the unique combinations of a pair of cards you can get out from a deck of 10 cards. All I did was to list out all the unique combinations, shuffle them and draw 1 combination from it (each combination has a pair of cards)

```
def chooseobjects(r):
    """
    Finds all unique pairs of cards in a deck of 10 cards.
    Mathematically, this is just nCr. i.e., 10C2 is 10 Choose 2.
    """
    results = list(itertools.combinations(["H[A]","H[2]","H[3]","H[4]","H[5]",
                                           "S[A]","S[2]","S[3]","S[4]","S[5]",
                                            ],r))
    return results

def draw(n,cards):
    """
    Draw n pair(s) of card from all the unique pairs generated from chooseobjects method.
    """
    random.shuffle(cards)
    return [cards.pop() for k in range(n)]

cards=chooseobjects(2) 
print("These are all the different unique combinations: "'\n',cards)
n=1
ding=draw(n,cards)
print("We randomly drew this pair: "'\n', ding)
print("The remaining unique pairs: "'\n',cards)
```

[image]

What I would like to do now is for those pairs that contain either 'H[2]' or 'S[4]', to be removed/deleted. Then return an updated list.

Any ideas? Let me know! Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
-ATTEMPT-

```
[p for p in cards if "H[2]" not in p and "S[4]" not in p]
```

The code above returns a list of tuples where H[2] and S[4] are not present.

Is there a more elegant way to implicit pass H[2] and S[4] into the list comprehension instead of having to explicitly declare/state them? Let me know!

EDIT 2: 
-SOLVED-

So, the solution is to append the two elements 'H[2]' and 'S[4]' into a list j.

```
j=[j for item in ding for j in item]
```

Note each element in list j is a string type. i.e.,

```
j[0] = H[2]
j[1] = S[4]
```

Then we create a list comprehension to iterate through each tuple in the 'cards' list. Where j[0] and j[1] does not appear in the tuple, we append them all to a new list!

```
[p for p in cards if j[0] not in p and j[1] not in p]
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at doing this?

Comment: I had a very poor attempt and did not include it in here. I will however add the attempt as soon as I get home.

Comment: Just added my attempt! Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is to append the two elements 'H[2]' and 'S[4]' into a list j.

```
j=[j for item in ding for j in item]
```

Note each element in list j is a string type. i.e.,

```
j[0] = H[2]
j[1] = S[4]
```

Then we create a list comprehension to iterate through each tuple in the 'cards' list. Where j[0] and j[1] does not appear in the tuple, we append them all to a new list!

```
[p for p in cards if j[0] not in p and j[1] not in p]
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you are storing the combinations of tuple in list as `my_list`. You may use *list comprehension* to filter the list as:

```
new_list = [card_pair for card_pair in my_list if 'H[2]' not in card_pair and 'S[4]' not in card_pair]
```

Here `new_list` will contain all the pairs not having `H[2]` and `S[4]` within it.

Comment: You are using the indices from a copy of the original, complete list to access a changing list. After the first deletion, you'd start getting incorrect indices. After the length of the list you're deleting things from becomes shorter than the index you're looking at, you'd get an `IndexError` on the next attempt at deletion.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, you were right. Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
cards = [(card1, card2) for (card1, card2) in cards if card1 not in ding[0] and card2 not in ding[0]]
```

Comment: Neither `card1` nor `card2` will be in `ding` because `ding` holds tuples while `card1` and `card2` are elements of those tuples. E.g., `'H[2]' in [('H[2]', 'S[4]')]` is `False`.

Comment: So, I think the general idea here is to access both elements 'H[2]' and 'S[4]'. Then iterate through the cards list and check if any of these elements exist. if they do, remove/delete the tuple.

Comment: So, he just needs to check in `ding[0]` instead.